# Generically creating object with n preceding singleton dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

Say I have matrix `X` with `X.ndim = n`. I now want to create a new matrix that has `n` "singleton" dimensions.

For example, when `n=2`, and I create a new range, I want to create it like

```
>>> bar = np.arange(0, 5)[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, ...]
>>> bar.shape
(1, 1, 5)
```

such that it has `2` singleton dimensions. Say `n = 5`. How would I generically generate my `bar` such that it has shape `(1,1,1,1,1,5)`?

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to create the new array specifying the `ndmin` parameter:

```
>>> np.array(np.arange(5), ndmin=6).shape
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5)
```

NumPy adds the new dimensions on the left.

Alternatively you could use `reshape` and pass in a tuple specifying the required shape:

```
>>> np.arange(5).reshape((1,)*5 + (5,)).shape
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> n=5
>>> bar = np.arange(0, 5)[(np.newaxis, )*n]
>>> bar.shape
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5)
```